# Can HTML I 'add to a page' communicate with HTML that was already there?

Tags: html

I'm not very familiar with HTML but am trying to learn just enough to help someone.  A page I'm working with gives me the option to 'Add HTML', which lets me add HTML script within a new box and displays it wherever it's placed.

Question;  Can the HTML I put in that box communicate with other things already existing on the page? If I for instance 'inspect element' on the page, would I be able to use the existing tags for anything?

Thank you - and I'm sorry if this question is terrible - again, very very new..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, all new elements can interact with existing elements